# How can I change the color of an already existing shape in p5.js?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

The solution is propably quite easy but I can't find a way myself. I want to create a standard shape (e.g. circle) and change its fill color some time later, but I can't find a way how to alter the attributes of an existing shape.

Example:

```
//circle is created and is filled black
fill(0,0,0)
p = circle(10,10,5) 

/*
...later
*/

p.fill_color = (255,255,255) // I want to change the color to white
```

Comment: You cannot change the color of a shape. You need to redraw the shape with a different color. It is common practice to redraw the entire scene in each frame.

Comment: To add a little depth on this issue, p5js is effectively an "immediate mode" graphics library (see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics) ), which means that as you call the drawing functions, the elements are immediately drawn to the canvas, and in order to make any changes, the drawing functions would need to be called again. This is in contrast to "retained mode" graphics libraries where graphical elements are treated as persistent objects that can be modified. Examples of "retained mode" libraries would be PixiJS and Fabric.js among others.

Answer (score 1):

As [Rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577765/rabbid76) said, you can't change the color of a shape you've already drawn. When you say `p = circle(...)`, the variable `p` isn't actually a circle. It's an object with many attributes, but the circle's position, size, and color are not among them. This means that you can't change attributes of the circle by changing attributes of `p`. Here's how I would solve this problem:

```
let p_fill;

function setup() {
  p_fill = color(0, 0, 0);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  fill(p_fill);
  circle(10, 10, 5);
}

function mousePressed() {
  p_fill = color(255, 255, 255);
}
```